# Converting 1-d array to 2-d array with overlapping

Tags: c++, audio, multidimensional-array, overlap, dimensions

I need to convert one dimensional array of size N to two dimensional array of size A*B > N. Let us take such case:

```
int oneDimensionalArray[6] = {7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15};
//then the second array would be
int twoDimensionalArray[2][4] = {{7, 8, 10, 11},
                                 {10, 11, 12, 15}};
```

This is used in so called overlap-add method used in digital sound processing. I have tried this approach which gives improper results:

```
   for(unsigned long i = 0; i < amountOfWindows; i++)
   {
       for(unsigned long j = hopSize; j < windowLength; j++)
       {
           //buffer without the overlapping
           if( (i * amountOfWindows + j) >= bufferLength)
               break;

           windowedBuffer[i][j] = unwindowedBuffer[i * amountOfWindows + j];
       }
   }

   for(unsigned long i = 1; i < amountOfWindows; i++ )
   {
       for(unsigned long j = 0; j < hopSize; j++)
       {
           // Filling the overlapping region
           windowedBuffer[i][j] = windowedBuffer[i-1][windowLength - hopSize + i];
       }
   }
```

I've also tried finding the relation using the modulo operation but I can't find the right one. This is the one that I've tried:

```
windowedBuffer[m][n % (windowLength - hopSize)] = unwindowedBuffer[n];
```

Comment: What do you mean? What's that 2?

Comment: Your overlap is `2`.

Comment: In the example, yes. But in general it's parametrized and equal to hopSize

Comment: Let's say we define `i` to iterate over the members of the 1D array. Then from `i` to `i + B - 1`, we copy the members of the original array into one row of the 2D one. After each copy, the iterator has to go back `k` steps where `k` is the amount of overlaps. So you'll just need to calculate the `k`.

Comment: Can you give us a larger example? And can you tell us if hop size will always be known or if you want to find it.

Comment: hopSize is constant throughout whole program and it is hardcoded at the beginning.

As far as wider example is concerned: we have a buffer of length 600
windowLength is 100
hopSize is 20
Values in the buffer are from range of -1 to 1
With no overlapping (hopSize = 0) we would have 6 windows
With overlapping given (hopSize = 20) we have 600/(100-80) = 7.5 => 8 windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already know `hopSize` (from your comment), what you want is simply:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < amountOfWindows; ++i) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < windowLength; ++j) {
        windowedBuffer[i][j] = unwindowedBuffer[i * hopSize + j];
    }
}
```

Where `amountOfWindows`, `windowLength` and `hopSize` are you parameters (resp. 2, 4 and 2 in your example).